# Android ArrayMap ClassCastException

Tags: android

i encountered a problem when i send a message by handler .

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]
at android.util.ArrayMap.allocArrays(ArrayMap.java:187)
at android.util.ArrayMap.put(ArrayMap.java:456)
at android.os.BaseBundle.putInt(BaseBundle.java:389)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.statistics.b.b(Unknown Source)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.statistics.b.a(Unknown Source)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.statistics.b.e(Unknown Source)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.AdSwitchLayout.j(Unknown Source)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.AdSwitchLayout.b(Unknown Source)
at com.easou.ecom.mads.AdSwitchLayout$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

**who can help me ?  thanks very much..**

This is my java code :

```
 try {
        Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_ACTION_COUNT);
        message.arg1 = event;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, id);
        bundle.putInt(KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE, type);
        bundle.putString(KEY_MESSAGE_PID, publisherId);
        message.setData(bundle);
        return message;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I very much doubt that this is the code that's generating the exception, since you are silently catching all exceptions and returning `null`. (You should at least log any caught exceptions.) Did you run the stack trace through `retrace` to decode the obfuscated method names?

Comment: @kkk I suggest you disable your code minification when you are debugging, so that you know exactly which line that gives error.

Answer (score 2):

Theres are something went wrong when ArrayMap try to dilatation its capacity.
This may related with a known issue [AOSP Issue 218944](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218944)

The way to work around this is to make sure ArrayMap have enough initial capacity.
So try to specific the capacity as you needed in constractor of Bundle.

```
Message message = mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_ACTION_COUNT);
message.arg1 = event;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(3);
bundle.putInt(KEY_MESSAGE_ID, id);
bundle.putInt(KEY_MESSAGE_TYPE, type);
bundle.putString(KEY_MESSAGE_PID, publisherId);
message.setData(bundle);
return message;
```

---

Follow the Bundle source code to make sure you have created ArrayMap with right initialCapacity.

```
/**
 * Constructs a new, empty Bundle sized to hold the given number of
 * elements. The Bundle will grow as needed.
 *
 * @param capacity the initial capacity of the Bundle
 */
public Bundle(int capacity) {
    super(capacity);
    mFlags = FLAG_HAS_FDS_KNOWN | FLAG_ALLOW_FDS;
}
```

Lead to BaseBundle

```
/**
 * Constructs a new, empty Bundle sized to hold the given number of
 * elements. The Bundle will grow as needed.
 *
 * @param capacity the initial capacity of the Bundle
 */
BaseBundle(int capacity) {
    this((ClassLoader) null, capacity);
}
```

Then comes to what realy effects

```
/**
 * Constructs a new, empty Bundle that uses a specific ClassLoader for
 * instantiating Parcelable and Serializable objects.
 *
 * @param loader An explicit ClassLoader to use when instantiating objects
 * inside of the Bundle.
 * @param capacity Initial size of the ArrayMap.
 */
BaseBundle(@Nullable ClassLoader loader, int capacity) {
    mMap = capacity > 0 ?
            new ArrayMap<String, Object>(capacity) : new ArrayMap<String, Object>();
    mClassLoader = loader == null ? getClass().getClassLoader() : loader;
}
```